# Difference between node, &node and node->next in link list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

```
// Program to insert node at front in linked list.
```

//This is a simple program in linked list but I do not understand the difference between
   // values of &newNode,newNode and newNode->next

```
void PushAtFrontLinkList(int value)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {

        head=tail;
    }
    node* newNode=new node();
    newNode->data=value;
    newNode->next=head; 
    head=newNode;


    // Trying to differentiate between data contained in newNode and &newNode and newNode->next
    cout<<"just new node"<<newNode<<endl; // what will be contained in newNode?     cout<<"address of node"<<&newNode<<endl; // what will be contained in &newNode?  
    cout<<"new node next"<<newNode->next<<endl; // It will be the address of the next node?


}
```

Comment: they are pointer to `node *`, pointer to `node` and pointer to `node` respectively.

Comment: Does that mean newNode should contain the same address as contained in newNode->next? In short will newNode contain some address or it will just contain the structure of node.

Comment: in expectation they should be different. but anything can happen while playing with pointers or you intend to make it so in the initial state.

Comment: @ HuStmpHrrr also, newNode contains the address of itself? newNode->next contain the address of next node?

Comment: newNode contains the node you just "newed". next contains the next node if you manipulate the pointer in a right way.

Answer (score 1):

The newNode will contain the the address for the new node object you just created. As for newNode->next, it contains the address for the next node in the list.

Note that at the end, newNode will be the head of the list, and newNode->next will be pointing to the old head.

Comment: thanks. But what would &newNode contain? If I want to pass the address of newNode to some other function (pass by reference)then will pass like function(newNode) or function(&newNode)?

Comment: You would use `function (newNode)`. That's because `newNode` is already an address. 

Note that you declared it as `node* newNode`. The type `node*` (with the asterisk at the end) is used to declare a variable that simply contains the address to a variable of type `node`, i.e. it's just a _pointer_.

Answer (score 0):

&newNode: The address in memory for the node
newNode: The node to manipulate
newNode->next: The node* pointer that is next.